# Add a resolver dynamically to react hook form?

Tags: react-native, yup, react-hook-form

I have a form which is generated dynamically after I call some APIs.
after the api response is received, I am resetting the form using the

```
const someModelObject = { name: "", isActive: 0, date: null }
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({ name: Yup.String().required(),
   isActive: Yup.number.required(), date: Yup.number().notRequired() })

const { reset } = useForm({
    defaultValues: someModelObject, 
    resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema) 
})
```

I am able to update the default values using reset function:

```
// after api call response
const moreCustomFieldsFromAPI = { custom1: "", custom2: "" }
reset({ ...someModelObject, ...moreCustomFieldsFromAPI })
```

But how do I update the resolver as it is obsolete when I add new form fields in the form controller?
I want a formatted object when I call getValues(), some key values are required in integer format and some in string.